# Jquery error in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

When I place the following jQuery code in JSP:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind("ready",function(){
        var recordPerPages=3;
        var currentPage=1;
        var trs=$("table tr");
        alert(trs);

        function create(pageNo){
            $("table").empty();
            var endRec=pageNo*recordPerPages;
            var stRec=endRec-recordPerPages;
            trs.each(function(indx){
                if((indx+1)>=stRec && indx<endRec){
                    $("table").append($(this))
                }
            })
        }
        create(currentPage)

        $("#prev").bind("click",function(){
            currentPage=currentPage-1
            create(currentPage)
        })

        $("#next").bind("click",function(){
            currentPage=currentPage+1
            create(currentPage)
        })
    })
</script>
```

Then I get the following error:

```
editListContributions.jsp:38:29: Illegal token.
       if((indx+1)>= stRec && indx <  endRec){

                        ^
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: In future questions, do not post "pls help asap". This is rude as you're basically putting pressure to us. This may be thus be counterproductive. We're volunteers, not your employees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen if you're actually using JSPX instead of JSP. JSPX is XML based. All [special characters in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) such as `<`, `&` and `>` (which represent respectively the start of a XML element, the start of a XML entity and the end of a XML element) needs to be escaped as `&lt;`, `&amp;` and `&gt;`.

```
if((indx+1)&gt;= stRec &amp;&amp; indx &lt; endRec){
```

An alternative to this unreadable mess is to put the entire script in a `CDATA` block.

```
<script>
    <![CDATA[
        ...
    ]]>
</script>
```

Much better is however to put JS code in its own `.js` file which you include by `<script src>`.

```
<script src="onload.js"></script>
```

#### See also:

- [Mozilla Developer Network - Writing JavaScript for XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML)

Comment: I tried with above code but not getting into the if condition

Comment: That's a different problem. Is your `editListContributions.jsp:38:29: Illegal token.` error now solved or not? I.e. it does not appear anymore and the JSPX page renders fine in webbrowser? If so, then just advance to the next problem. The current one is solved.